# looking for book title from about 1965 - 70. cars versus humans

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a book I read in the late 1960s. The storyline features cars attacking humans in a sort of rebellion. I think the title was some variation of Long Weekend or Three Day Weekend, but that turns up no results.
This predated AI or computers in cars, but anticipated automobles developing an intelligence of their own (from memory!)

Comment: Wow! That was quick. Thanx heaps. Now just to find a copy ...

Comment: It was so long ago that the quality or otherwise of the writing is but a blurr. The storyline and concept, though, have always stayed with me and come to mind whenever I read about autonomous cars/ Teslas and their computer updating etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. *[The Four Day Weekend](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/george-h-smith/four-day-weekend.htm)* ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?589477)) by George H. Smith.

[image: The Four Day Weekend - book cover]

Found by searching on ISFDB for titles with "weekend" and looking for 1960s books.

The blurb is transcribed in [this review](http://www.trashfiction.co.uk/four_day_weekend.html):

> It was impossible, of course, because the machines had been ruling everything for 100 years, so what could they revolt against?
> They decided people had outlived their usefulness to them, and that genocide of 4 billion people on Planet Earth was the best policy.
> And into this incredible situation Charles Henry Hyde was thrust, with a shrew of a wife named Agnes who nagged like it was 1966...

Comment: That last line is even worse than it sounds. The book was *published* in 1966.